# What exactly happened to Chen Dawai?

Tags: plot-explanation, blackhat

I saw Blackhat (2015) yesterday and was a bit confused about that part. Warning, **spoilers** ahead:

How exactly did Chen Dawai (the friend of Nick Hathaway aka Chris Hemsworth) die?

Was the car rigged with explosives prior to all of them starting the drive? Or did the bad guys blow it up with some kind of rocket launcher?

It just exploded out of the blue with the bad guys showing up behind it, but it was not really clear to me *why* it exploded.

Comment: There was a particular scene a few scenes earlier. When they were all meeting to eat (I think while *Hathaway* did his inofficially granted attack on the NSA) they were tracked through the streets by some guys and one of them fiddles around under some car, supposedly *Chen*'s.

Answer (score 1):

"Dawai is killed in a car bombing"
This means that he was killed by the Bomb that one of the bad guys planted underneath his car a couple of scenes before. Here is the 
[IMDB statement about death](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackhat_(film))

The rocket launcher shown was just to be used at them later on. He was killed in car bombing and not by launcher. If he had used the launcher, we would have seen some smoke coming out of it or him reloading it but soon after the car explodes, the bad guy is shown with launcher still in his hands and without any smoke or even reloading it. He was aiming it at something else.